# ¿Están correctos los parámetros en QFont?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy tratando de asignarle diferentes tipo de fuentes a mi aplicación con PyQt5, pero a la hora de elegir otra fuente que no sea 'Roboto' no sé como se le especifica, ya que no me está tomando la fuente.

```
QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Roboto-Light.ttf")
QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Static/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf")
self.label_content.setFont(QFont('Roboto [LightItalic]'))
```

[image: foto de la estructura de directorio de mi proyecto]

Comment: " Roboto-Light.ttf " se encuentra al mismo nivel que Static, por eso la ruta es diferente a la de lightItalic,la moví a la raiz del proyecto para comprobar si no tenía un problema de rutas

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def load_fonts_from_dir(directory):
    families = set()
    for fi in QDir(directory).entryInfoList(["*.ttf"]):
        _id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(fi.absoluteFilePath())
        families |= set(QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(_id))
    return families


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    font_dir = CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "Static" / "fonts"
    families = load_fonts_from_dir(os.fspath(font_dir))
    print(families)

    db = QFontDatabase()
    styles = db.styles("Roboto")
    print(styles)

    font = db.font("Roboto", "Medium Italic", 12)

    # OR
    # font = QFont("Roboto", pointSize=12, weight=QFont.Medium, italic=True)

    label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    label.setFont(font)
    label.setText("Hello world!!")
    label.resize(640, 480)
    label.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, funcionó.

Comment: @LeoOdriozola ¿tienes 2 cuentas con el mismo nombre? Por otro lado deberias dar credito a mi respuesta del sitio en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68521723/6622587